# Customizing response serialization in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to customize the way types are serialized to the response in ASP.NET Core MVC?

In my particular use case I've got a struct, `AccountId`, that simply wraps around a `Guid`:

```
public readonly struct AccountId
{
    public Guid Value { get; }

    // ... 
}
```

When I return it from an action method, unsurprisingly, it serializes to the following:

```
{ "value": "F6556C1D-1E8A-4D25-AB06-E8E244067D04" }
```

Instead, I'd like to automatically unwrap the `Value` so it serializes to a plain string:

```
"F6556C1D-1E8A-4D25-AB06-E8E244067D04"
```

Can MVC be configured to achieve this?

Comment: I think your best bet is a custom `JsonConverter`. JSON.NET is used as the default JSON serializer, so consult their docs.

Comment: start from reading about [custom-formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters)

Comment: @ChrisPratt that seems to be the way to go. I thought there is something more generic (if I ever wanted to return XML instead of JSON, I'd have to configure another formatter), but it'll suffice.

Comment: You can try overriding `ToString` on your struct. That'll effect more than just serialization, though.

Comment: I've tried it already, but it seems that JSON.NET ignores it. I'll go with custom `JsonConverter` for now and perhaps suggest a more generic solution on MVC issue tracker.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can customize the output produced by JSON.NET with a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

In your case, it would look like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AccountIdConverter))]
public readonly struct AccountId
{
    public Guid Value { get; }

    // ... 
}

public class AccountIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => objectType == typeof(AccountId);

    // this converter is only used for serialization, not to deserialize
    public override bool CanRead => false;

    // implement this if you need to read the string representation to create an AccountId
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!(value is AccountId accountId))
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Expected AccountId object value.");

        // custom response 
        writer.WriteValue(accountId.Value);
    }
}
```

If you prefer not to use the `JsonConverter` attribute, it's possible to add converters in `ConfigureServices` (requires `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json`):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new AccountIdConverter());
        });
}
```

Comment: That's almost how I ended up doing this. I just don't like the `JsonConverter` attribute so I added my converter to `SerializerSettings.Converters` in `ConfigureServices`' `AddMvc`

Comment: I've added your alternative to my answer, for completeness.

Comment: This also works with `AddControllersWithViews`, which is what's used in the React.js template with Visual Studio 2019.

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyAwesomeConverter());
        });