# How can I override the JSON serialization for a property, to serialize the value as a string instead of an object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Using .Net 4.8 I have all my entity framework classes inheriting from an AbstractBase:

```
public abstract class AbstractBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedTimestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime UpdatedTimestamp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual User LastModifiedByUser { get; set; }

    public string ToActiveInactive()
    {
        return this.ActiveFlag ? "Active" : "Inactive";
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I am ignoring the `CreatedByUser` and `LastModifiedByUser`.
What I would like to do instead is somehow replace the User object
with a property called FullName
which the User object can provide like

```
User test = new User();
test.GetFullName();
```

My User object already has this so my question is there a way to do this so I do not have to write more implementation of the same logic every time I want to serialize an entity class?

Comment: What does _"replace the User Object with a property called FullName which the User Object can provide like"_ mean? Your example code doesn't explain that. Do you mean you want to give `AbstractBase` a property `string FullName => CreatedByUser.GetFullName();`?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1.htm) like the one shown in the [Newtonsoft documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) to serialize your `User` class as a string:

```
public class UserConverter : JsonConverter<User>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, User value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.GetFullName());
    }

    public override User ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, User existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var fullName = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        // Or construct a User and return it, if you can do so from the fullName.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that your question does not provide enough information for me to write the  [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1_ReadJson.htm) method. If you need to support deserialization, you will need to fully implement this method by constructing a `User` from the `fullName` string.

Now, to use the converter, you have several options:

1. If you only want the `User` properties of `AbstractBase` to be serialized as strings, apply the converter to the `User` properties using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) as follows:

   ```
   public abstract class AbstractBase
   {
       [JsonConverter(typeof(UserConverter))]
       public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

       [JsonConverter(typeof(UserConverter))]
       public virtual User LastModifiedByUser { get; set; }

       // Remaining properties and methods unchanged
   ```
2. If you want all instances of `User` of to be serialized as a string, you can apply it directly to `User` as follows:

   ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(UserConverter))]
   public class User
   {
       // Properties and methods unchanged
   ```
3. Or, you could add it to your [asp.net-web-api2](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api2) global [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm).  To do this in .NET Framework, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44642045/3744182) to *[Json.net global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15066904/3744182)* by [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2061604/andrei).  For .NET Core 2.x see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49189185/3744182) to *[Customizing response serialization in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49179047/3744182)* by [Métoule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2698119/m%C3%A9toule).
4. .NET Core 3.x and later use a difference serializer, [system.text.json](/questions/tagged/system.text.json), so you will have to use a different approach in that version, or revert back to using Json.NET as shown in *[Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fuCL5x).